# Looping numbers with object values and push output to a array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, loops, for-loop, object

This is for a line chart. Some values are available in the object "filteredTime" and need to fill "0" for unavailable values in the object.

for loop match with object values and push the output to the selected array. Object number of items are dynamic.

Expected outcome is 10 items Array. My output is 20 items array according to 2items in the object. Solution required for dynamic number of items in the object when looping.

```
let dataa = {
  datasets: [{ data: [] }],
};

let filteredTime = { 4: "13.50", 7: "12.50" };

for (let step = 1; step <= 10; step++) {
  for (var i in filteredTime) {
    if (step != i) {
      dataa["datasets"].map((filteredPerson) => {
        filteredPerson.data.push(0);
      });
    } else {
      dataa["datasets"].map((filteredPerson) => {
        filteredPerson.data.push(filteredTime[i]);
      });
    }
  }
}
```

**Output**

```
Array(20): [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, "12.50", 0, 0, 0, 0, "13.50", 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

*"**filteredTime**" Object items number are **dynamic**.*

**Expected Output:**

```
Array(10): [0, 0, 0, "12.50", 0, 0, "13.50", 0, 0, 0, ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)

```js
let filteredTime = { 4: "13.50", 7: "12.50" }

let result = Array.from({length: 10}, (v, i) => filteredTime[i + 1] || 0)

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let dataa = {
  datasets: [{ data: [] }],
};

let filteredTime = { 4: "13.50", 7: "12.50" };

  for(let i=1;i<=10;i+=1){
    if(!filteredTime[i]){
      dataa.datasets[0].data.push(0)
   }else{
      dataa.datasets[0].data.push(filteredTime[i])
  }

}
```